# Correct way to send auth headers via ajax request to an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, api, xmlhttprequest

I have a form where I've stored the auth key in a hidden field.

```
hidden_field_tag 'auth_key', Settings.biometric.auth_key
```

I am sending an ajax request to an API where I'm setting the auth key in the header which requires the key:

```
var authKey = $("input[id='auth_key']").val();
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader ("auth", authKey);
}
```

All is working fine, just that the auth key resides in the form and is easily inspectable by any malicious user.

I think this might not be the right way to do this
What is the best approach to perform this?

Comment: Can't you change `$("input[id='auth_key']")` to `$('input#auth_key')`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh that is not related to the solution.

Comment: I know. That's why i didn't add it as an answer. Only a comment. Wanted to improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

Anyone who has access to the client-side (a.k.a your User using a browser), can ultimately find a way to get this `auth_key`, because a client-user has and will always have power/access on what "data" gets sent/received/stored, especially easier here in webapps because of built-in browser developer tools.

### Some Explanations:

*Disclaimer: I am not well versed in this field, so if anyone, please let me know.*

- Yes, it can be encrypted in the client-side, but a user/hacker can decrypt them because the "encryption" trace can be found somewhere in your JS script file:

  ```
  // application.js example
  ...beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    var encryptedAuthKey = localstorage.get('encrypted-auth-key');
    var decryptionPassword = 'abcd';
    var authKey = doSomeFancyDecryption(encryptedAuthKey, decryptionPassword);
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("auth", authKey);
  }
  ```
- However, a secure way would be to encrypt them using a password stored in the server-side, so that the client cannot debug/inspect/find this password in the JS code... except that this is not possible, see below:

  ```
  // application.js example
  ...beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    var encryptedAuthKey = localstorage.get('encrypted-auth-key');

    var decryptionPassword = someFunctionThatPerformsAjaxRequestToServerAndReturnsTheDecryptionPassword();
    var authKey = doSomeFancyDecryption(encryptedAuthKey, decryptionPassword);

    function someFunctionThatPerformsAjaxRequestToServerAndReturnsTheDecryptionPassword() {
      // do some ajax request with Auth header equals Something...
      // ummm... what's the value of this something?
      // ummm... I cannot pass in my Username and Password, of course!
      // ummm... I cannot pass in another-kind of "auth_key", which just basically loops this process itself.
    }

    xhr.setRequestHeader ("auth", authKey);
  }
  ```
- You can "sign" your request so that you won't need to directly supply anymore the `auth_key` as part of your request (but the client-user can still hack this and get the auth-key and create their own request themselves, precisely because they can see and have access to your underlying code like below):

  ```
  // application.js example
  ...beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    var authKey = localstorage.get('auth-key');
    var params = // assign all input fields as key-values object here
    var url = this.url;
    var signature = generateSignatureUsingHMAC(authKey, url, params)

    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Signature", signature);
  }
  ```

**I would personally do something like the signature-based authorization above**

Comment: The last approach makes sense to me